# How to prevent users from circumventing shared file restrictions?

Tags: windows-10, permissions, filesystems

I was employed by a school to setup a shared folder between classes and therefore everyone in that class can access the shared files by the teacher but cannot write to them. However, upon testing, a major exploit was found:

1. Student cannot write to file, but wants to cause mischief.
2. Student goes to file properties, edits security and grants himself write permissions.
3. Student is able to write to file and even deny teachers' access.

When the folder was configured, the school wanted everyone to have read AND write access because in some files, they need to write stuff into them. However, certain files (rules & regs, annoucements, etc.) can only be written by the teacher, but as stated above there is away to circumvent this?

Comment: It sounds like the student has admin authority over their computer and whatever the common device is. Set up 2 groups of files: 1 where students CAN write to and 1 where students CANNOT write to (Read only, not modify change, save or write - just Read).

Comment: "Change permissions" is a permission you have allowed for that group.  As long as someone has it, it makes the other permissions pointless.  You will find it under "Special Permissions".  Also.. keep in mind that Windows has combined network and NTFS permissions as if they are one.. they call it "Simple Permissions" they are NOT one but you have to really hunt through the dialogs to see the differences.

Answer (score 0):

> Student goes to file properties, edits security and grants himself write permissions.

This is only possible **if the student already has the "Change Permissions" permission.** The simple answer is to not grant it in the first place.

Without this permission, only the object's owner is allowed to edit its ACL. Because the student didn't create the file, they wouldn't be its owner and wouldn't be able to bypass the above permission requirement.

(The only two other reasons why a student would be able to bypass this both boil down to "the student somehow has Admin rights on the file server" and if that's the case, then that's a big problem in itself.)

> When the folder was configured, the school wanted everyone to have read AND write access because in some files, they need to write stuff into them. However, certain files (rules & regs, annoucements, etc.) can only be written by the teacher

If the folder itself is writable, then you cannot really undo that for  just a few individual files – even if you make a file read-only, someone could just delete that file (through having the "Delete child objects" permission on the folder) and create a new one.

So don't make the whole thing publicly writable. Instead, create several sections – read-only announcements can go at the root, but student uploads should have their own separate subfolders.

- "Shared" – teacher 'Modify', students 'Read'
- "Shared\Put your assignments here" – teacher 'Modify', students 'Read, Create'
- "Shared\Memes" – teacher 'Modify', students 'Modify'
- And so on.